# How to grep for the whole word

Tags: unix, grep

I am using the following command to grep stuff in subdirs

```
find . | xargs grep -s 's:text'
```

However, this also finds stuff like `<s:textfield name="sdfsf"...../>`

What can I do to avoid that so it just finds stuff like `<s:text name="sdfsdf"/>`

OR for that matter....also finds `<s:text somethingElse="lkjkj" name="lkkj"`

basically `s:text` and `name` should be on same line....

Comment: Did anyone read the title as "how to grep for the whole **world** "?

Comment: @Earlz, no, mostly because I Googled "grep whole word".

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You want the `-w` option to specify that it's the end of a word.

`find . | xargs grep -sw 's:text'`

Comment: So, what does the `s` argument do?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica suppress error messages. Try grep --help, will give info on the valid options

Answer (score 107):

Use `\b` to match on "word boundaries", which will make your search match on whole words only.

So your grep would look something like

```
grep -r "\bSTRING\b"
```

adding color and line numbers might help too

```
grep --color -rn "\bSTRING\b"
```

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html:

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
>     word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last
>     character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string,
>     where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: Single Quotes also work as in `'\bword\b'`

Comment: `-r` is the recursive way.

Answer (score 33):

You can drop the `xargs` command by making grep search recursively. And you normally don't need the 's' flag. Hence:

```
grep -wr 's:text'
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `-w` option for whole word match. Sample given below:

```
[binita@ubuntu ~]# a="abcd efg"
[binita@ubuntu ~]# echo $a
abcd efg
[binita@ubuntu ~]# echo $a | grep ab
abcd efg
[binita@ubuntu ~]# echo $a | grep -w  ab
[binita@ubuntu ~]# echo $a | grep -w  abcd
abcd efg
```

Comment: `-w` is not POSIX way, on some UNIX-like distribution `grep` does not have such option

Answer (score 4):

you could try rg, https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep :

```
rg -w 's:text' .
```

should do it

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17780631)

Comment: I did provide the answer: rg -w 's:text' .

Comment: There may be other reasons to suggest a nonstandard tool, but as a solution to a question about how to solve this with standard `grep` this is not particularly compelling or satisfying, especially given that `grep` has the same option.

Comment: It depends on how deep and fat the directi

Comment: It depends on the number of files, ripgrep can be much faster and the find->xargs creates a new process for each file.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of setting the boundaries of the word, note that it doesn't work without the quotes around it:

`grep -r '\<s:text\>' .`

Comment: the quotes are because of your shell. but yeah, use them it is easier. another example: `grep \\\<s:text\\\>` (i.e. escape the `\ ` and then the `<`)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter out the remainder text part, you can do this.

`xargs grep -s 's:text '`

This should find only `s:text` instances with a space after the last t. If you need to find `s:text` instances that only have a name element, either pipe your results to another `grep` expression, or use regex to filter only the elements you need.

Comment: what if the "text" is at the end of the output? Will it not be skipped in your solution?