# Whole-word matching on a body of text, given a list of words

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell, grep

**Note:**

Before I get down to business, I'd like to point out some other SO posts that didn't quite answer my question and are not duplicates of this one:

- [How to grep with a list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863301/how-to-grep-with-a-list-of-words)
- [How to make grep only match if the entire line matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-grep-the-exact-match)
- [how to grep for the whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879085/how-to-grep-for-the-whole-word)
- [Grep extract only whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616012/grep-extract-only-whole-word)

**Background:**

I have a list of words in a file called `words.txt` (one word per line). I would like to find all lines from a different, much larger file called `file.txt` that contain any of the words from `words.txt`. However, I only want *whole-word* matches. This means that a match should be made when a line from `file.txt` contains at least one instance where a word from `words.txt` is found "all by itself" (I know this is vague, so allow me to explain).

In other words, a match should be made when:

1. The word is all by itself on a line
2. The word is surrounded by non-alphanumeric/non-hyphen characters
3. The word is at the beginning of a line and followed by a non-alphanumeric/non-hyphen character
4. The word is at the end of a line and preceded by a non-alphanumeric/non-hyphen character

For example, if one of the words in `words.txt` is `cat`, I would like it to behave as follows:

```
cat              #=> match
cat cat cat      #=> match
the cat is gray  #=> match
mouse,cat,dog    #=> match
caterpillar cat  #=> match
caterpillar      #=> no match
concatenate      #=> no match
bobcat           #=> no match
catcat           #=> no match
cat100           #=> no match
cat-in-law       #=> no match
```

**Previous research:**

There's a `grep` command that *almost* suits my needs. It is as follows:

`grep -wf words.txt file.txt`

where the options are:

```
-w, --word-regexp
       Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.
       The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning
       of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.
       Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a
       non-word constituent character. Word-constituent characters are
       letters, digits, and the underscore.
-f FILE, --file=FILE
       Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line. The empty file contains
       zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

The big problem I'm having with this is that it treats a hyphen (i.e. `-`) as a "non-word constituent character". Therefore (based on the example above) doing a *whole-word* search for `cat` will return `cat-in-law`, which is not what I want.

I realize that the `-w` option probably achieves the desired effect for many people. However, in my particular case, if a word (e.g. `cat`) is followed/preceded by a hyphen, then I need to treat it as if it's part of a larger word (e.g. `cat-in-law`) and not an instance of the word by itself.

Additionally, I know I could alter `words.txt` to contain regular expressions instead of fixed strings and then use:

`grep -Ef words.txt file.txt`

where

```
-E, --extended-regexp
              Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression
```

However, I would like to avoid altering `words.txt` and keep it free of regex patterns.

**Question:**

Is there a simple bash command that will allow me to give it a list of words and perform *whole-word* matching on a body of text?

Comment: If you have a big list of constant words, use the ternary tool to generate a trie regex. Its much faster than simple alternations, and you can pick the boundary you need, screenshot [here](http://www.regexformat.com/default_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg). Take a look at how they made dictionaries into a single regex. The trial version is free. If its ever changing word list (dynamic), this won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I finally came up with a solution:**

```
grep -Ef <(awk '{print "([^a-zA-Z0-9-]|^)"$0"([^a-zA-Z0-9-]|$)"}' words.txt) file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `words.txt` is my list of words (one per line).
- `file.txt` is the body of text that I would like to search.
- The `awk` command will preprocess `words.txt` on-the-fly, wrapping each word in a special regular expression to define its official beginning and ending (based on the specifications posted in my question above).
- The `awk` command is surrounded by `<(` and `)` so that its output is used as the input for the `-f` option.
- I'm using the `-E` option because I'm now inputting a list of regular expressions instead of fixed strings from `words.txt`.

The nice thing here is that `words.txt` can remain human-readable and doesn't have to contain a bunch of regex patterns.

Comment: Just want to say thank you. I've wanted some solution like this from time to time, and finally found one.