# How to search for whole words with grep?

Tags: grep

If I have the file `foo`:

```
read_from_buffer
read_from_buffer_and_file
write_to_buffer
some_other_function
```

then using

```
cat foo | grep 'read_from_buffer'
```

will list 2 lines:

```
read_from_buffer
read_from_buffer_and_file
```

But I want only exact matches... How to tell `grep` that different character must come than character: `0-9a-zA-Z_`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to grep for the whole word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879085/how-to-grep-for-the-whole-word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
grep -w 'read_from_buffer' foo
```

---

From `man grep`:

> `-w, --word-regexp`: Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches that form **whole words**.  The test is that the matching substring must
>                 either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent  character.   Similarly,  it  must  be
>                 either  at  the  end  of  the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are
>                 letters, digits, and the underscore.

or

> `-x, --line-regexp`: Select only those matches that exactly match the **whole line**.  (-x is specified by POSIX.)